# Comentando blocos de código, IPython Notebook

Tags: ipython-notebook

É muito chato ter que comentar linha por linha, e fico querendo juntar um editor poderoso (como o Vim) ao IP-Notebook.

Mas deve haver uma forma de comentar blocos de código de forma simples.

Minhas versões:

- IP-Notebook: 1.1.0
- Chrome: 31.0.1650.63

Comment: Apesar de ter descoberto como fazer o que eu queria, continuo querendo editar no Vim, dentro do ypnb. Será possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para comentar blocos de código, basta selecionar as linhas de código que deseja comentar (não precisa selecioná-las por completo, ou seja, até o final da linha) e pressionar CTRL+/.

O mesmo serve para descomentar um bloco de código.

Answer (score -2):

Eu peguei um notebook com teclado padrão ABNT e estava batendo cabeça para achar as teclas de atalho...

o <CTRL+/> funciona nos teclados padrão US... no ABNT (que tem o 'ç' do lado direito da tecla do 'L'), e a tecla de atalho (na tentativa e erro) foi o <CTRL+;>.

e, de quebra, aumento de indentação <CTRL+[>, e diminuição de indentação <CTRL+´>...

Comment: Carlos, IPython Notebook eh uma ferramenta de programacao python. Nao tem nada a ver com o hardware. Por isso vc recebeu downvote. Vejo que vc eh novo aqui, entao, vale a dica de olhar as tags e dar uma lida na pergunta antes de tentar uma resposta. :)

Comment: As teclas de atalho standard do Jupyter Notebbook/Lab variam de acordo com o teclado utilizado.